# How to make a private variable modifiable?

Tags: php

```
<?php

class MyClass {
  private $init;

  public function __construct () {
    $this->init = "Hello World";

  }
}

?>
```

Hi guys, need your help.

If I have a private variable $init in MyClass, how would I write a method which allows $init to be modifiable after instantiation?

Comment: This is PHP 101 OOP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php Just create a normal method as you did with the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setters and getters.

```
class MyClass {
    private $init;

    public function __construct () {
        $this->init = "Hello World";

    }

    public function getInit(){
        return $this->init;
    }

    public function setInit($init){
        $this->init = $init;
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
$myClass = new MyClass;
$myClass->setInit("New Init");
echo $myClass->getInit();
```